# Django ManyToManyField reverse relationship issues

Tags: python, django, model

I have 3 models, `Industry` has a `ManyToManyField` to `Client` and `Contact` has a `ForeignKey` to `Client`.  When I go to the django admin, `Contact` and `Industry` both display the correct widgets and allow for choosing the relationship and they seem to work.  But if I try to access a `Client` I created, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /admin/project/client/
__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
```

another perhaps error occurs when trying to create a `Contact` without setting a `Client`:

`NOT NULL constraint failed: project_contact.company_id`

what could be missing in the `Client` model setup that could be causing these problems?

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    clients = models.ManyToManyField('Client', related_name='industries', blank=True)

    def get_clients(self):
        return ", ".join([c.clients for c in self.clients.all()])    

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    clients = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='contacts', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['id', 'name', 'contacts', 'industries']

class IndustryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'get_clients']

class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'company']

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
admin.site.register(Industry, IndustryAdmin)
```

Comment: May I ask what is it you want to access by adding related names to `Client`'s admin list display (i.e. `'contacts', 'industries'`)??

Comment: Had assumed it would show the reverse relationship once set.     Is this not possible in django admin?

Comment: By using regular admin page that is impossible because it doesn't understand how to convert a queryset (i.e. reverse relations or `M2M` relations) and it is not a field type like model's fields. There are some ways that you can show this type of relation in admin list, but they are not optimize ways. Suppose your relations grow larger, therefore your admin page becomes really slow each time you want to see this page and it also loses it's readability. We usually show `Many2Many` and `One2Many` relations in object  detail not in objects list.